# How to deploy RSWebParts.cab manually?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, moss

I'm using the SSRS 2005 Web parts to display my reports in a MOSS 2007 SP1 Portal. I have successfully installed the Web parts in my development, testing, and UAT servers using the following command: **stsadm -o addwppack -filename *path/to/RSWebParts.cab***. But when I tried running the same command in the production server, it will give me the following error:
*This solution contains no resources scoped for a Web application and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application.*

I know I usually will get this kind of error message when I tried to deploy my custom solutions having no Web application resources (such as web.config entries) to a specific Web application. But this is not my custom solution, it is an out-of-the-box SSRS Web part and it does have resources scoped to a Web application.

I tried to even use different combination of the command by providing the -url, -globalinstall, and -force switches but it still give the same error.
The configuration of the 4 servers are exactly the same, both from software and hardware perspectives. All other features are working properly on the production server.

I even tried to extract the cab file manually to the bin folder of my Web application, then modify the Web.config manually to include the SafeControl element (copied from the manifest.xml inside the cab file). But it gave me an error saying it couldn't find the resources file. Even though, I extracted the whole file, including the resource files in the bin folder.

Is there anyone who can help me resolve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried all possible combinations of the command?

The following combination works well for all of the web part packs we install:

**stsadm -o addwppack -filename *path/to/RSWebParts.cab* -globalinstall -force -url *ContentURL***

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it with the following command and it worked successfully. Do not add any extra things. The following code copies `RSwebparts.cab` in `C:\` directory.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\BIN>
stsadm.exe -o addwppack -filename C:\RSWebParts.cab -globalinstall -force
```

Cheers & enjoy